# Pymongo : skip line in cursor

Tags: cursor, pymongo

How to skip a line in cursor. I used next() but I got an error.
Here is my code:

```
for row in cursor:
           if(...):
             move to next line
           else :
              ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for row in cursor:
   if (...):
      continue

   standard logic here....
```